# How do I handle Ctrl-C interrupt in nim?

Tags: nim-lang

If I press Ctrl-C while my program is running it exits and prints `SIGINT: Interrupted by Ctrl-C`.

How do I ignore the Ctrl-C interrupt in Nim on Linux?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can control the behaviour of `Ctrl+C` with [setControlCHook](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#setControlCHook%2Cproc%29):

```
proc ctrlc() {.noconv.} =
  echo "Ctrl+C fired!"

setControlCHook(ctrlc)
```

Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> calls the `ctrlc` procedure. It's up to that procedure to ignore the SIGINT, or to clean the house and exit with [quit](https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#quit%2Cstring).